# How to hide the arrows which appear during log in process via image code on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I have some security concerns regarding the image log in method on Windows 8. When I enter the image code the arrows and circles appear for approximately 1 second. It is enough time memorize the pattern for the person behind you. How to disable the appearance of the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it might be enough time, depends on people involved. [Such questions](https://superuser.com/questions/491192/are-the-windows-8-password-pin-picture-password-options-all-equally-secure) are subjective however and likely to be closed.

Read the [**Optimizing picture password security**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/optimizing-picture-password-security) article on the **Building Windows 8** blog for more details about the feature. AFAIK it is [not possible](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fa3d7b3-2256-405a-8d8c-79f2a768f706/disable-visual-feedback-of-the-picture-password-while-it-is-used-to-sign-in-to-a-windows-8-pc?forum=W8ITProPreRel) to disable the visual feedback, which IMO is stupid (sure people might make more mistakes this way, but turning it off should be an option). My personal recommendation is to use a traditional lengthy complex text password (which is anyway the fallback for multiple failed picture password attempts).